# Python sound modules not working (Circular Import)

Tags: python, audio, module

After installation of playsound and simpleaudio modules to try simple commands in order to play some audio files I always get the following message.

```
playsound: ImportError: cannot import name 'playsound' from partially initialized module 'playsound' (most likely due to a circular import) (/Users/joaosoares/Documents/PySound/playsound.py)

simpleaudio:AttributeError: partially initialized module 'simpleaudio' has no attribute 'WaveObject' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I am currently using python 3.8.1, I've tried to create a new environment using pipenv and the problem persists. **I got it to work the very first time I installed playsound**. The problem might came after I had to install AppKit.NSSound as needed to run simplesound. My problem may be obvious and I apologise in advance if my issue isn't clarified I started to use python very recently.

I am following this [tutorial](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#recording-audio)

Comment: can you show your code. Have you called your own script playsound causing a conflict with the playsound module?

Comment: So is your file called playsound.py?

Comment: No my file is simply named test.py

Comment: Well no it isn't, should I delete this tread? It's pretty pointless now and this is my first post I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: So you have only one file? called test.py? cause your questions says "playsound file:" then shows code like thats why you have put in a file called playsound.py

Comment: I thought I had it named test.py and I had put simpleaudio.py and playsound.py.
Thank you so much Chris!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way i can reproduce your error is if i create a file called `playsound.py`

```py
from playsound import playsound

playsound('myfile.wav')
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/stackoverflow/stackoverflow.py", line 1, in <module>
    from playsound import playsound
  File "C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\stackoverflow\playsound.py", line 1, in <module>
    from playsound import playsound
ImportError: cannot import name 'playsound' from partially initialized module 'playsound' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Chris\PycharmProjects\stackoverflow\playsound.py)
```

In your question your error specifically says your file is called playsound.py

`/Users/joaosoares/Documents/PySound/playsound.py`

rename this to something else otherwise it will try to import its self

Comment: This was exactly the problem, I feel kind of embarrassed.
Thank you so much for your time Chris!

Answer (score 0):

There is Error in playsound Module So I has solved it for beginners
Hope so it's useful for you

Write This Command in Terminal that is provided in the image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6zcN.png
And Then Again Run the Python File and  the Error is Solved
Now you can play sound using playsound module
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQiNN.png
Note : Use double \ in path if you are a windows user else use \ in Mac and also enter Correct Path of song

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just uninstall the current version by typing:

pip uninstall playsound

then install the older version by typing:

pip install playsound==1.2.2

Answer (score -1):

just remove that ***playsound*** (use another name)  and you are done

Comment: This is not a complete answer, it doesnt explain why your solution works, and I dont even know if this answers the question.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the problem was in fact a circular import.